# Cannot connect to local mumble server

Tags: networking, router, mumble

I am struggeling to setup my own local mumble server.

Setup:

- Windows 8
- Mumble 1.3.0 Snapshot
- Mumur 1.3.0 Snapshot

What I have done so far:

- Installed and configured mumur (mumble server) with the murmur.ini
- Opened Port 64738 in my Fritzbox router for UDP and TCP (each from 64738 to 64738 at port 64738)
- Tested the opened port with http://www.canyouseeme.org/ -> Successful
- Allowed mumble in windows firewall
- Started the mumble server and the client both with admin rights to be sure
- Tried to connect with my local(127.0.0.1), my intra(192.168...) and my Internet-IP(79.224...) -> all without success
- Friend tried to connect from outside the network with my internetip -> no success

I am getting the following error in my serverlog:

```
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.543 MurmurIce: Endpoint "tcp -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6502" running
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.543 Murmur 1.3.0 (1.3.0~384~g916dcc0~snapshot) running on WinX64: Windows 8 x64 - 6.2.9200: Booting servers
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.558 1 => Server listening on [::]:64738
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.574 1 => Server listening on 0.0.0.0:64738
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.590 1 => Failed to bind UDP Socket to 0.0.0.0:64738
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.590 Bonjour: Failed to load dnssd.dll
<W>2014-09-23 18:47:46.605 1 => Not registering server as public
```

Using `netstat -ano | find ":64738"` I get:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:64738          0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         1304
  TCP    [::]:64738             [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         1304
  TCP    [::]:64738             [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         1304
  UDP    [::]:64738             *:*                                    1304
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

This issue has been fixed by using the older 1.2.8 stable version!

Comment: "Failed to bind UDP Socket to 0.0.0.0:64738" - Anything else using that port?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. is there a way to find out? using `netstat -ano | find ":64738"` does find 3 TCP and 1 UDP ports. If I close mumble and mumur those entries go too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled mumble. This time I used the stable 1.2.8 stable. This immediately worked!